# How to create a controller in a sub-folder when defining as a parameter?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I'm creating a project with Laravel and I'm aware that there is a way to create the migration and controller (with or without resources) along with the model with `php artisan make:model ExampleModel -m -c -r`.

In my project I have models and controllers in sub-folders. I'm able to add the model and controllers to sub-folders when creating them separately (`php artisan make:model Models/example_model` and same in controllers). But I don't know how to add the controllers to a sub-folder when creating them with a parameter on the make:model command.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

> I've tried the below commands already and they don't appear to be working
>
> `php artisan make:model Models/example -m -MyControllers/c -r`
>
> `php artisan make:model Models/example -m MyControllers/-c -r`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure it's possible with the `make:model` command. My best guess is to use 2 commands:

`php artisan make:model Models/NewModel -m`

`php artisan make:controller MyControllers/NewModelController -r`

Answer (score 2):

This will create sub-folder for both models and controller and files into it

```
php artisan make:controller TestFolder\TestController --model=Models\TestModel
```

I hope this helps.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Glade to help you :)

Comment: What happened to my answer i think it is still considered to be up-voted, Don't you think ?

Comment: Remove Models, as its going to be created inside Models folder and confuse structure 

php artisan make:controller TestFolder\TestController --model=TestFolder\TestModel