# Create model, controller and migration using single command in diffrent folders

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

Well I see [This stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43187735/laravel-5-4-create-model-controller-and-migration-in-single-artisan-command) question and that's very close to my issue, but I want something like that with this difference:

> My models are inside `app/Model` folder
>
> My controllers are inside `app\Http\Controllers\Web` folder

As much as I  know, answer which is mentioned in [this post's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43187735/laravel-5-4-create-model-controller-and-migration-in-single-artisan-command) can help me to just define first rule using

```
php artisan make:model Model/MyModel -mcr
```

that would be make `controller` inside `app\Http\Controllers` folder itself.

**Is there any way that I can define the target folder for `Controller` in my custom folder using this single line command?**

***Note:***
I saw [this question and answers too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55324115/how-to-create-a-controller-in-a-sub-folder-when-defining-as-a-parameter) but it's not single line command.

Comment: @TruongDang please read the question again. I'm talking about `single line command`

Comment: You have made your custom command for it. You can take a reference from here
https://github.com/appzcoder/crud-generator/blob/master/src/Commands/CrudModelCommand.php

Answer (score 1):

I know you can do it through the controller command as the `--model` flag accepts value, so this would work, but you cannot create a migration through the controller command.

```
php artisan make:controller Web/YourController -r --model=Model/YourModel
```

and this won't work

```
php artisan make:model Model/YourModel --controller=Web/YourController -rm
```

But you can write your [own command](https://laravel.com/docs/master/artisan#generating-commands)
 for this.